# How can I use SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName method to get details of long filepaths?

Tags: c++, windows

I have been trying to get the metadata of files using the SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName method. When I pass long filepath(greater than 260 characters) with the "//?/UNC/" prefix, I get the error "The parameter is incorrect", and when I pass the filepath without the "//?/UNC/" prefix, I get the error "The specified file could not be found". What is the format in which we need to pass the long filepath to the SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName method in order to get the metadata?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think your question would be easier to understand if it would include code samples of whyt you describe.